# How to import empty column in mysql database to textbox in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This code currently import data into various textbox as long as they contain information. When any column is null, this code does not work please how can i solve this.

```
 mysql = "select ProfilePics, FullName, Address,Email,Phone1,Phone2,Gender,AccountNumber from mydb.MembersAccount Where AccountNumber ='" & SearchBox.Text & "'"
            mysqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(mysql, mysqlcnx)
            mysqlred = mysqlcmd.ExecuteReader
            mysqlred.Read()
            arrimage = mysqlred.Item("ProfilePics")
            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrimage)
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream)
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("FullName")
            AddressTextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("Address")
            MailTextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("Email")
            Phone1TextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("Phone1")
            Phone2TextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("Phone2")
            GenderTextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("Gender")
            AccNoTextBox.Text = mysqlred.Item("AccountNumber")
            mysqlred.Close()
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the value is null before to assign it to the textbox:

```
If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(mysqlred.Item("FullName")) then

   FirstNameTextBox.Text =""
else 
   FirstNameTextBox.Text =mysqlred.Item("FullName")
End if
```

or :

```
if mysqlred.Item("Phone2") = DBNull.Value then 
 Phone1TextBox.Text =""
```

etc.

Hope this help you